# Is it correct to use .reduce and filter in 1 million json array in node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, memory-management

Is it correct to use .**reduce** and .**filter** in 1 million json array in node js? I am using **JSONStream** to parse it. However I need to find the duplicate and unique records and have to do some massage on every records and also have to **comparisons** between two json array of 1 millions. 
What is the best way to approach this? Performance is not a constraint its a background job only.  Planning to deploy this job aws ECS using scheduled task. 
I am planning to do something like this below

```js
                 var values = [
 { name: "a", age: 15 },
 { name: "a", age: 17 },
  { name: "a", age: 17 },
 { name: "b", age: 18 },
 { name: "c", age: 18 },
  { name: "d", age: 18 },
    { name: "c", age: 18 },
];
 
const lookup = values.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.name] = ++a[e.name] || 0;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log("Name count",lookup)

var unique =[];
var dup = values.filter(e => {
    if(lookup[e.name]){
      return lookup[e.name];
    }else {
      unique.push(e)
    }
});

console.log("Unique:",unique);
console.log("Duplicate", dup)
```

Comment: There's no definition of "correct" here and there's no code to show us what actual things you're trying to do such that we could offer ideas for "efficient" ways to do those things.  As such, there's not much we can do with this question.  There would be at least memory usage ***consequences*** if you use `.filter()` on a million element array (as that makes a copy of at least part of the data).  `.reduce()` is just a method of iterating the array so it really depends upon what the `.reduce()` callback is doing as to whether that's an issue or not.

Comment: Comparing two giant arrays may just be a CPU exercise which you don't seem worried about at all, but again it really depends upon exactly what you're doing.  So, either show us the actual code for the things you need to do or this question will likely get closed as one that doesn't contain enough detail to provide any meaningful answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated the code, I have to find the unique and duplicate records. The Total record count will be 1M, I am doubtful that above code will run or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether this is going to work with a million record array, then you will just have to run it on your system and in your environment to see.  That isn't something one can just look at the code and "know".  You have to experiment.

I'd have to say that I start out thinking that a million record set of data is probably best managed in a database.  If you put all these in a database, then you could structure how you put the data into the database to make it easier to query for all the records with a given name or age or all the records that have a unique name or a non-unique name.  This is what databases are built for.

I can see one way that might speed things up a bit.  You can build `lookup`, `unique` and `dup` with fewer name lookups.  If, while you are building the `lookup` data structure, you also just keep track of all the items with that particular name, then you can just see which items end up with only one item for a name.  So, rather than iterate through all the data and lookup every name, you can just iterate through the lookup data structure and see which names have a cnt of `1` or greater than `1`.

I also personally like using a `Map` object for the lookup since that's what it is built for, but since your keys are strings, your object will probably work just fine too.  Anyway, here's a slightly tweaked version:

```
var values = [
    { name: "a", age: 15 },
    { name: "a", age: 17 },
    { name: "a", age: 17 },
    { name: "b", age: 18 },
    { name: "c", age: 18 },
    { name: "d", age: 18 },
    { name: "c", age: 18 },
];

const lookup = new Map();
const unique = [];
const dup = [];

for (let item of values) {
    let array = lookup.get(item.name);
    if (!array) {
        // if we don't have this name yet, add it to the Map as a one element array
        lookup.set(item.name, [item]);
    } else {
        // otherwise, just push this item into the array
        array.push(item);
    }
}

// To find unique and dup, we can just iterate the Map and 
// look at the length of each array
for (let [name, array] of lookup) {
    if (array.length === 1) {
        unique.push(array[0]);
    } else {
        dup.push(...array);
    }
}

console.log("Name count", lookup);
console.log("Unique:", unique);
console.log("Duplicate", dup);
```

---

The `values` data structure is not the most efficient way to store a million records that all have the same two properties.  It's possible that the interpreter will recognize the internal repetition and optimize it for you, but it could probably be stored more efficiently as:

```
const values = [
    [ "a", 15 ],
    [ "a", 17 ],
    [ "a", 17 ],
    [ "b", 18 ],
    [ "c", 18 ],
    [ "d", 18 ],
    [ "c", 18 ],
];
```

Or, even just:

```
const values = [
    "a", 15,
    "a", 17,
    "a", 17,
    "b", 18,
    "c", 18,
    "d", 18,
    "c", 18,
];
```

where the code had some pre-built knowledge for how to get each individual item.  You could consider optimizations like this if the memory usage was too high.